# How to divide a circle into $100$ arcs?

Tags: geometry

let me explain with a picture:
[image: Circule!]

Simply I need to find 100 points like 3π/2, 5π/3, 7π/4, ... in circle but I don't know how could to find them.

In this picture the circle is divided into 16 parts, But I need to divide it using 100 points.

Comment: What don't you understand? $2 \pi$ is the full angle. If you divide it into 100 parts you get a hundred $\frac{2 \pi}{100} = \frac{\pi}{50}$ angles.

Comment: Make your questions clear.

Comment: Use increments of $4$ grades.

Comment: @HirekKubica there are a lot of ppl they don't know that 2π is a full angle. Thanks

Comment: @Vahid Well, maybe... But that's basic trigonometry (geometry even). I would expect anyone with access to education to know it by the age of 15.  Besides you have it laid out on the picture, that's the reason I was confused as to what's the issue for you.

Comment: @HirekKubica, Thats OK, but again there are a lot of ppl they had not a good education. BTW thanks for help.

Comment: this question has no answer, unless you mean 100 evenly spaced points? That's not what the diagram is showing

Comment: @gebra, yes I mean 100 evenly spaced point but in same format that showed in picture. I mean like this: 2π, π/6, π/4, ...

Comment: How is pi/6 a multiple of 2pi/16?. Its pi/8, 2pi/8, 3pi/8 ... 16pi/8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac 1{100}$ circle is $\frac \pi{50}$ radians or $3.6^\circ$  You can certainly add that much to any starting point (dropping down to zero when you cross $2\pi$ radians or $360^\circ$.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I still have some issues, I tried 1 x π/50 but It draw the point on about π/4 in shape. What's wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it draw the point'?  What is "it" that is doing the drawing?

Comment: It's a computer software development system. I give it the star, end, radius of points, then It draw the arch.

Comment: I found it: Start Point + (π/50 x Percent). Thanks to RossMillikan and @HirekKubica